# Converting datarow[] to xml. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, xml, datarow

I have one application, in that i am using a datarow object like this.

```
DataRow[] drRow;
                drRow = _dsmenu.Tables["tblmenu"].Select("id='" + DocID + "'");
```

After this i make some changes in columns like this

```
drRow[0]["Allow"] = "Yes";
```

after all the changes, i need to save that particular datarow as a xml to the db.
I can do the dataset to the xml by getdataset() method. But i need to save only that particular datarow. Is it Possible? If yes please help me. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. I recommend you to do it this way.

```
    DataRow[] rows = _dsmenu.Tables["tblmenu"].Select("id='" + DocID + "'");
    rows[0]["Allow"] = "Yes";

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
    {
        table.ImportRow(row);
    }

    table.WriteXml(""); // Take this into database.
```